# What's the Purpose of setting the clientID for JMS publisher / consumer?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I understand that i need to set the clientId and subscription name when writing the jms topic subscriber for my durable topics.

But Whats the purpose of setting the clientID when publishing the TOPIC ? I have seen people setting the client Id even for publisher / consumer, but no one explained that why it is required.

```
ConnectionFactory conFactory =  this.getConnectionFactory();
Connection connection = conFactory.createConnection();

connection.setClientID("WHATS_MY_PURPOSE"); // Why do we need clientID while publishing the TOPIC from consumer / publisher

connection.start();
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `clientId` is required to uniquely identify an application. It's a must when using a durable subscription in Pub/Sub messaging pattern. As you might be aware, a messaging provider caches publications destined for durable subscriber applications when they are off-line. When such applications come on-line again, a messaging provider has to identify `OK, this is the same application that created a durable subscription but went away for reason. Now it has come back. So let me deliver all messages that were published when this application was away`. To verify it's the same application, messaging provider compares the `clientId` of the application with `clientId` available with cached subscription information.

Comment: which application you are referring to here? The subscribers i reckon? No question about the subscribers we need to have clientID.

But how it is significant for the publishers? A publisher is having the clientID ?

Comment: According to JMS 1.1 specification, it is durable subscriber application. As JMS is API specification, it is possible that some messaging providers might use it for other purposes also. I am not aware of anyone though.

Comment: Okay here is my scenario.

1. Publisher is sending the message on Queue and setting the clientID  (say ABC) as well

2. Durable Subscriber is picking that message with a clientID (say ABC)

Above is working fine without any issue.

But it is working fine even if i stop setting the clientID from the publisher and just keep setting the clientID for subscriber only e.g.; below situation is working fine as well and not causing any issue.

1. Publisher is sending the message on Queue without setting the clientID

2. Durable Subscriber is picking that message with a clientID (say ABC)

Comment: As I said above, it is not required for publisher to set clientId. It's must for durable subscription.

Comment: I would not set ClientID for connections used for publishing and/or queue consumers. If the ClientID is set, it won't be possible to use multiple connections with that ID (from multiple nodes, threads, processes, etc).