# Artemis JUnit with durable shared subscription

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I'm using the `artemis-junit` dependency

```
testImplementation("org.apache.activemq:artemis-junit")
```

with Spring Boot 2+, and I have 2 JMS listeners with the following configuration:

```
destination = "my.topic"
clientId = "sharedApp1" 
subscription = "mySharedSub"
durable = "true"
shared = "true"
```

I want to verify that shared subscription work but when I run the JUnit test the second listen throws

```
ActiveMQDuplicateMetaDataException[errorType=DUPLICATE_METADATA message=AMQ229035: Metadata jms-client-id=sharedApp1 had been set already]
```

stack-trace:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:412) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:380) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:818) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Is this by design (developer aid), as I'm running in the same JVM? or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is by design. It's a violation of the JMS specification to have multiple concurrent JMS clients using the same client ID. Section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification says this:

> The purpose of client identifier is to associate a connection and its objects with a state maintained on behalf of the client by a provider. By definition, the client state identified by a client identifier can be ‘in use’ by only one client at a time. A JMS provider must prevent concurrently executing clients from using it.

Keep in mind that the client ID is *optional* for JMS 2 shared durable subscriptions. Section 4.2.2 of the JMS 2 specification states:

> A *shared durable subscription* is identified by name and an optional
> client identifier, and may have several consumer objects consuming
> messages from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58679284/setting-clientid-for-jms-2-0-consumer where you quote the folllowing: The spec says the same basic thing about shared durable subscriptions in section 8.3.4:

    A shared durable subscription is identified by a name specified by the client and by the client identifier if set. If the client identifier was set when the shared durable subscription was first created then a client which subsequently wishes to create a consumer on that shared durable subscription must use the same client identifier.

Comment: So after removing the clientId the test is now successful, but I think by spec what I was doing should be allowed. Nevertheless, not using the clientId seems more versatile as it can be shared even by different application (i.e. different clientIds). But please clarify this before I mark the answer as the solution. Thanks Justin.

Comment: What you were doing is not, in fact, allowed by the specification. I've clarified my answer on this point referencing to the applicable section of the spec.

Comment: The bit from the spec that I cited on the other answer that you linked is simply stating that *if* you set the client ID when you create the subscription then you need to use that same client ID when reconnecting to the subscription later. It's not saying that multiple consumers can use the same client ID.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are running the test inside the same JVM and is not possible due to the following validation (org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection):

```java
private void validateClientID(ClientSession validateSession, String clientID)
     throws InvalidClientIDException, ActiveMQException {
  try {
     validateSession.addUniqueMetaData(JMS_SESSION_CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY, clientID);
  } catch (ActiveMQException e) {
     if (e.getType() == ActiveMQExceptionType.DUPLICATE_METADATA) {
        throw new InvalidClientIDException("clientID=" + clientID + " was already set into another connection");
     } else {
        throw e;
     }
  }
}
```